# start mysql server at boot for debian

Tags: debian, mysql, startup

I am using Debian Etch and I have following [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28) and tried to write a script like this to auto start mysql server at boot:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/blah
#

# Some things that run always
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I used `update-rc.d` also, but mysql server don't start at boot, why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no reason for you to write this script. `/etc/init.d/mysql` *is* an `init(1)` script, so just use that:

```
# update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to look into the more advanced `update-rc.d` options. For instance, maybe you are using an uncommon runlevel, and the default runlevels for the provided `mysql` script don't include that.

If you were actually trying to get something to run on startup which doesn't already provide an init script, you'd need to remove the `sudo` bit. init scripts run as root already. You actually have to *drop* permissions if you need your program to run as another user.

Comment: for some unknown reason this always has stated: `insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (3) of script 'mysql' overwrites defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 4 5 6) of script 'mysql' overwrites defaults (0 1 6).`
I had to `update-rc.d mysql remove` and then do `update-rc.d mysql defaults` this fixes it. If you want to know which runlevel youre running use `who -r`